# SQL Split String at char and then Split each into individual chars() as a view or just select

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split

I have a column of data that looks like this:

```
xy w12,jwwx  , mpp w,a n p ,234567
```

Notice the items are csv which is easy enough to separate; however I have some other requirements making this more difficult.

I need the Split Strings (inclusive of any spaces from comma to comma) to be in rows.

Of course the last requirement is that each of those strings also be split into columns of chars inclusive of spaces and in order. (maximum will never be more than 8 chars)

I need to create a row of data for each split that looks like

```
             char(1) | Char(2) | char(3) | char(4) | char(5) | char(6) | char(7) | char(8)
```

---

```
row1:            x        y                   w         1        2

row2:            j        w         w         x

row3:                     m         p         p                  w

row4:           a                   n                   p

row5:           2         3         4         5         6        7
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff MS-SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just want the `substring()` function (which can also go by `substr()` in some databases):

```
select substring(col, 1, 1) as char_1,
       substring(col, 2, 1) as char_2,
       . . .
       substring(col, 8, 1) as char_8
from t;
```

EDIT:

The above assumes the strings are in separate rows, which makes much more sense to me.  Assuming that commas are not valid characters, use `string_split()` (or a related function that you can readily find on the web):

```
select substring(str, 1, 1) as char_1,
       substring(str, 2, 1) as char_2,
       . . .
       substring(str, 8, 1) as char_8
from t cross apply
     string_split(t.data, ',') ss(str);
```

Comment: Ok so I split the strings into columns and then on each column I substring ? And if the string does not have 8 chars will I get an error ??

Answer (score 0):

Just another option using a little XML and a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'xy w12,jwwx  , mpp w,a n p ,234567')

Select A.ID
      ,char1 = substring(RetVal,1,1)
      ,char2 = substring(RetVal,2,1)
      ,char3 = substring(RetVal,3,1)
      ,char4 = substring(RetVal,4,1)
      ,char5 = substring(RetVal,5,1)
      ,char6 = substring(RetVal,6,1)
      ,char7 = substring(RetVal,7,1)
      ,char8 = substring(RetVal,8,1)
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(SomeCol,',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  char1   char2   char3   char4   char5   char6   char7   char8
1   x       y               w       1       2       
1   j       w       w       x                       
1           m       p       p               w       
1   a               n               p               
1   2       3       4       5       6       7
```